# Create Clickable verification link PHP mail

Tags: php, html, email

For email verification, I am creating a hash for each user and then sending a verification email to the user.The message body is given below.

```
 $message_body = '
        Hello '.$first_name.',

        Thank you for signing up!

        Please click this link to activate your account:

        http://www.alphaktu.co.in/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash  ;
```

But I want to convert the verification link to a clickable link.

Comment: if you are sending your mail using html MIME type then you can add plain html in your body will convert into html. like
<a href="http://www.alphaktu.co.in/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash'">Verify email</a>

Comment: sent email as html , and include <a href = 'link'>link</a> 
(also at end you can write a line, click / copy paste link in url)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you already knew about the [HTML Link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp). So what is the real issue?

Comment: Are you using php mail function? I recommend using a mail Framework instead.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you might want to use HTML links within your email body, something like this:

```
  $message_body = '

    Hello '.$first_name.',

    Thank you for signing up!
    Please click this link to activate your account:

    <a href="http://www.alphaktu.co.in/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash.'"> 
         Verification Link 
    </a>'  ;
```

Secondly, for this to actually work, you need to use the HTML MIME type when setting headers for your email. If you haven't, it will look something like this:

```
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

This basically tells the browser to interpret the HTML code with your message body as actual HTML, and not plain text.

Comment: yeah that will make your email land in spam in most of cases